# JS or CSS issue

Tags: javascript, css

The page in question is [this](https://valgoverblik.dk/search/).

Upon the page load, the page is not starting from the top.

I am using a script there with ID **show_results**. It seems this is causing some issue there.

I have already used CSS like below there without any success:

```
#show_results {
    position: relative;
}
```

Where am I wrong? What am I missing there to make the page start directly from the top?

Thank you.

Comment: *it starts from below the search box* What starts? Please be much more clear as to what problem you are having and what your question is.

Comment: It works now………

Comment: When you open the above URL, it should load from very top of the page. But after complete lage load, you can notice that the page starts after the search form. You need to scroll the page to the top to see the search form. I have confirmed that it was due to the class #show_results. If I remove that, the page loads from very top. When I add that class, the page loads from where that class is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what causing your site problem:
 `document.getElementById("show_results").scrollIntoView();`

You should probably add a check as when it should be called, and not simply call it every time.

If you could provide with more information as what you exactly wanted to achieve with that I could take a look and help you with that.

Comment: Hi John, Thank you for your reply. I just want my page to load from the very top. Not half the way. Now when you open the site, it is not loading from the very top.

Comment: Yes I saw that, and this line of code is causing your problem `document.getElementById("show_results").scrollIntoView();` if you remove it or add another condition to when it should be actually called you'll see that the page will load from top.